# Evaluate $L(1, \chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_5(n)}{n},$ for $\chi$ mod $5$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-character

My HW question is:

> Evaluate the series
> $$L(1, \chi_5) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_5(n)}{n},$$
> where $\chi_5$ is the unique nontrivial Dirichlet character mod $5$.

My work is:
\begin{align*}
        L(1, \chi_5) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_5(n)}{n} &= \frac{\chi_5(1)}{1} + \frac{\chi_5(2)}{2} + \frac{\chi_5(3)}{3} + \frac{\chi_5(4)}{4} + \frac{\chi_5(6)}{6}  + \frac{\chi_5(7)}{7} + \cdots \\
        &= 1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} + \cdots \\
        &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots\right) \\
        &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5n + 1} + \frac{1}{5n + 4} - \frac{1}{5n + 2} -\frac{1}{5n + 3}.
    \end{align*}
Now, we define
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{5n + 1}}{5n + 1} 
    + \frac{x^{5n + 4}}{5n + 4} - \frac{x^{5n + 2}}{5n + 2} - \frac{x^{5n + 3}}{5n + 3}$$
and differentiate termwise to find that
\begin{align*}
        f'(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n} + x^{5n + 3} - x^{5n + 1} - x^{5n + 2}\\
        &= \frac{1}{1 - x^5} + \frac{x^3}{1 - x^5} - \frac{x}{1 - x^5} - \frac{x^2}{1 - x^5} \\
        &= \frac{1 + x^3 - x - x^2}{1 - x^5} 
    \end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
        f(1) &= \int_0^1 \frac{1 + x^3 - x - x^2}{1 - x^5} \\
        &= .43041  \quad \text{(using Wolfram-Alpha)}.
    \end{align*}

However, a direct [computation in wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DirichletL%5B5%2C%201%2C%202%5D) gives $4\pi^2/25$ which is about 1.57.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: " where $\chi_5$ is the unique nontrivial Dirichlet character $\mod 5$ "? There are $4$ Dirichlet characters $\mod 5$, three of them non-trivial. The one you are trying to calculate as index $3$ in the Wolfram enumeration. Also, you misplaced the arguments: `Dirichlet[5,1,2]` corresponds to $\sum_{n} \frac{\chi_1(n)}{n^2}$. The one you want is `Dirichlet[5,3,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is good, but your use of Wolfram alpha is not as what you want is [$L(5,3,1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DirichletL%5B5%2C%203%2C%201%5D) which indeed gives your result (note that the way Wolfram Alpha works $L(5,1,s)$ is the $L$ of the trivial character evaluated at $s$, so $L(5,1,2)=(1-1/25)\zeta(2)=\frac{24 \pi^2}{6 \times 25}=\frac{4 \pi^2}{25}$

Then the character are indexed by generators so $L(5,2,s)$ computes the complex $L$ corresponding to the generator character $\chi_{5,2}$ and then $L(5,3,s)$ computes the $L$ for the unique real Dirichlet character.

Note that modulo $5$ there are $3$ nontrivial characters, but indeed only one is real.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Is there a good resource in general on how to use wolfram-alpha for number theory methods in general?

Comment: not sure - for me trial and error generally works and sometimes looking at their documentation examples

Answer (score 3):

When $\chi$ is a real primitive character modulo $q$, it is well known that

$$
L(1,\chi)=-{1\over q^{\frac12}}\sum_{1\le r\le q}\chi(r)\log\sin{r\pi\over q}\tag1
$$

if $\chi(-1)=1$ and

$$
L(1,\chi)=-{\pi\over q^{\frac32}}\sum_{1\le r\le q}r\chi(r)\tag2
$$

if $\chi(-1)=-1$. In the case of OP, $\chi_5$ is the unique real primitive character modulo $q=5$, we use (1) to conclude that

\begin{aligned}
L(1,\chi_5)
&=-{1\over\sqrt5}\log\left(\sin\frac\pi5\sin{4\pi\over5}\over\sin{2\pi\over5}\sin{3\pi\over5}\right) \\
&={2\over\sqrt5}\log{\sin(2\pi/5)\over\sin(\pi/5)}={2\over\sqrt5}\log\left(2\cos\frac\pi5\right)\approx0.43041
\end{aligned}

Comment: Can't be that well known because I've never seen this before

Comment: See chapter 6 of Davenport's _Multiplicative Number Theory_.

Comment: Does it appear in *Introduction to Analytic NT* (Apostol)? That is the book I am studying now.

Comment: No, but you can derive it yourself using results concerning Gauss sums

Comment: "Can't be that well known because I've never seen this before."  That comment will not age well. When you are first studying a subject, there are *many* imporant things that you don't know yet in the subject. These formulas for $L(1,\chi)$ when $\chi$ is a primitive quadratic character are extremely standard in number theory because they lead to explicit formulas for the class numbers of quadratic fields. Besides their appearance in Davenport's book, already mentioned, they can be found in many other books.

Comment: See also (2.20) and (2.21) on p. 336 in Borevich & Shafarevich's *Number Theory* (their formula has a Gauss sum $\tau(\chi)$, which is calculated in Theorem 7 on p. 349), Theorem 9.9 (p. 288) in Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I* (Gauss sums are in Theorem 9.17 on p. 300), p. 272 in Overholt's *A Course in Analytic Number Theory* (Gauss sums are calculated on p. 273), pp. 256-257 in Janusz's *Algebraic Number Fields* (2nd ed.) and Theorem 4.9 on p. 37 in Washington's book *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields*. And that is just citing books I have easy access to right now.